# GetGlyphOutline() and UTF-16 surrogate pairs

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts

I'm using the GDI [GetGlyphOutlineW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the outline of unicode characters, and it works fine except that it does not work with surrogate pairs (U+10000 and higher). I've tried converting the surrogate pair into a UTF-32 character, but this does not appear to work.

How can I get glyph outlines of Supplementary Multilingual Plane characters?

Comment: I know it's been a while, bit I'm curious if you (or anyone else) found a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Some Suggestions:

- Does the particular Unicode code point you are trying to get actually exist in the font that is selected in the DC passed to the GetGlyphOutlineW function?
- Follow the [directions on this page](http://winvnkey.sourceforge.net/webhelp/surrogate_fonts.htm) to enable surrogate pairs in Windows.
- Use the [Uniscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions for character manipulation.